# Tkinter gui only plots figure when window is being resized

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, resize

I have a script that embeds a simple plot into a Tkinter gui. There is a button to plot, when it pressed it seems to do nothing, yet if the window is even slightly resized the plot pops up. The gui window is large enough to contain the plot, what am I doing wrong here?

***Code***

```
print('\n'*3)
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

#MAKE ROOT WINDOW
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
#root.geometry("600x450")

#MAKE A FIGURE OBJECT
my_figure = Figure(figsize = (4, 4), dpi = 100) 

#MAKE A FRAME WIDGET
frame1 = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
frame1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.N, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
frame2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)

#MAKE A CANVAS OBJECT
my_canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(my_figure, master = frame1) # creating the Tkinter canvas containing the Matplotlib figure  

# TURN THE CANVAS OBJECT INTO A CANVAS WIDGET
my_canvas.get_tk_widget().pack() # placing the canvas on the Tkinter window
my_canvas.draw()

def plotData():
    plot1 = my_figure.add_subplot(111) # adding the subplot 
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = [11, 3, 6, 9,12]
    plot1.plot(x, y, marker='o', c='b')

# MAKE BUTTON TO PLOT GRAPH
button1 = tk.Button(frame2, text = "Plot", command = plotData, relief = tk.GROOVE, padx =20, pady =20 )
button1.pack(side="right")

root.mainloop()
```

***Desired outcome***

A gui window which does not need to be resized to see the plot.

Comment: You need to call `my_canvas.draw()` at the end of `plotData()` function.

Comment: @acw1668   Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `my_canvas.draw()` at the end of `plotData()`:

```py
def plotData():
    plot1 = my_figure.add_subplot(111) # adding the subplot 
    x = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y = [11, 3, 6, 9,12]
    plot1.plot(x, y, marker='o', c='b')
    my_canvas.draw() # draw the graph
```